# What is the Settings.settings file for?

Tags: c#, asp.net

#### what files are these ?

***hi every body***

> while reading about about coding with c# and asp.net i notice that
>   files which  are  (Settings.settings)  and the other is
>   (Settings.Designer.cs) which in one of project  layers what kind of
>   files are they and why he use them ??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Those are [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), that can be easily edited as a cleartext, human-readable file, and which can be accessed during design-time (and runtime) as classes and properties.